# MySQL – How do you find the time down to the Millisecond?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to get the time down to the Millisecond in MySQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support milliseconds in any of the time / date columns, or return it in `NOW()` so unfortunately, no.

If you have a string in a date / time + microseconds format you can use `SELECT MICROSECOND('1997-12-31 23:59:59.000010');` to extract the microseconds.

Comment: Old topic, but since I recently had this issue, it's possible by using a user defined function UDF (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share it since I recently needed milliseconds for a MySQL project as well.

You can write a UDF - [User Defined Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-udf.html) - to get you the system time down to a fairly small fraction of a second:

[image]

You can grab the sourcecode, as well as the pre-compiled binary [here on github](https://github.com/CarnotInteractive/MySQL-udf-microtime).